# SVG animation combine @keyframes

Tags: css, animation, svg

I'm creating an SVG animation of a router.
This is not very exciting but I have the following question.

The router has different colors for every side. Every side has it's own class.
Currently my color-filling looks like this:

```
@keyframes router_base 
{   
    0% {
        fill: #85d1d3;
    }   
    50% {
        fill: #85d1d3;  
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }   
    100% {
        fill: black;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    } 
 }
```

This tells the `router_base` that 50% of the given time it stays `#85d1d3` and the last 50% it goes to black.

Every side has it's own color so in this example I should create a `@keyframe` for every color.
This looks like it could be done smarter....

Here is a fiddle of the entire thing.
https://jsfiddle.net/yzzubxgf/

Comment: I am not sure if that can be done with one re-usable animation but it can be done with two re-usable animations like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yzzubxgf/1/). Let me know if it helps and if it does, I will post as answer.

Comment: No not really the problem remains. The idea is that first all lines a drawn and then the colors fill. Because every side has it's own color I thought that it might be possible to do this in one `@keyframe` for every color

Comment: The need for more than one animation is only because you say every side has its own color. Making the lines get drawn before the fill transition is a simple thing. It just needs the delay to be adjusted like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yzzubxgf/2/). (I changed the stroke color to make it more visible.)

Comment: Yes I know but that doesn't solve my "issue" I think I just need to create a `@keyframe` for every color.... The thing is that this is a very complex svg in total so it's a lot of coding :-)

Comment: If you have to create one keyframe for every color, you'd need 4/5 keyframes but with this approach you'd need only 2 keyframes at all times. Anyway that's your choice.

Comment: Yes. Thnx for your time and input

Answer (score 0):

If using sass you could create a mixin that will generate the code for the different animations like this:

```
@mixin createKeyFrames($animationName, $color1, $color2 : black) {
  @keyframes #{$animationName}
  {   
      0% {
          fill: $color1;
      }   
      50% {
          fill: $color1;  
          stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }   
      100% {
          fill: $color2;
          stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      } 
   }
}
```

And then call it

```
@include createKeyFrames(router_base, #85d1d3);
```